# Making a Histogram from multiple tables using a 'For' Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a histogram for three different variables from 13 different tables. For simplicity, I will call these variables 'x', 'y', 'z'. i.e. I need to make one histogram for all the x variables over all 13 tables, one histogram for all the y variables over all 13 tables, and one histogram over all z tables. The 13 different tables had 10k+ rows for multiple variables, so I had to do a boolean to select 'good' values. So far I have:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for itable in range(len(numtable)): #making a for loop to cycle through each table, over the length of the amount of tables
    for ival in range(len(boolean)): #the tables I am working with consider each value from the above loop as an array. i.e. if I want all the x vals from one table it will make an array of them instead of one value.
        plt.hist(x = 'x', bins = 20)
```

What I am getting is a histogram with only 3 bins of equal height. I am not the most experienced with coding, so how do I make it so I make a histogram from all the x values across all tables? I know I can use np.append(values) to basically make a new table of all the values I need, but I need to access other variables from the 13 tables for the values, so I can't make a separate table. Any and all help would be awesome[image]

I have added a picture of the values I am getting for 'x' and my histogram

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for combining histograms on the single plot. One way if the overall column width is split between different columns. As a minimal example, try

```
plt.hist([[1,2,3],[1,1,2]])
```

Another option is to use transparency, see, e.g., make histogram actually overlap. A minimal example is below.

```
plt.hist([1,2,3], bins=3, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist([1,1,2], bins=3, alpha=0.5)
```

Note that in this approach, it is beneficial to set up the number of bins to be identical.

For your code above:

```
to_plot = list()
for itable in range(len(numtable)):
    for ival in range(len(boolean)):
        to_plot.append(itable[ival]) # or any other way to refer to the numbers
plt.hist(to_plot)
```

or

```
for itable in range(len(numtable)):
    for ival in range(len(boolean)): 
        plt.hist(x='x', bins=20, alpha=0.5)
```

respectively.